# How to manipulate ansible facts?

Tags: automation, ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-facts

I was trying to figure out f there is a way to manipulate ansible facts, for example if `ansible_default_ipv4.address` = `10.100.1.7` then assign `10.253.1.7` to some variable in playbook.

So basically I just want to replace second octate of `ansible_default_ipv4.address` from `100` to `253`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @ydaetskcoR. You should show what you have tried so far. Since this is tricky, I am providing a solution. There may be a better solution, but this one works.

```
  vars:
    myip: 10.100.1.7

  tasks:
  - set_fact: newip="{{ myip | regex_replace('^(\d+)\.100.(\d+\.\d+)$', '\\1.253.\\2') }}"
  - debug: var=newip
```

Answer (score 0):

I can help as regard getting the value of a nested element in Ansible 2.5.5 (I use the nameserver as example). You can use:

```
"{{ansible_dns.nameservers[1]}}"
```

You can then replace the 1 digit by using item integer in loops or simila.